How to upload a custom signing key for multi-tenant enterprise application?
Background: I want to provide custom claims in an Azure Identity token. I have a registered application in the tenant “BaseTenant.” I’ve also registered this application in two other tenants: “Customer 1” and “Customer 2.”
The Problem: To provide custom claims in the ID token, I need to create a custom signing key for each customer tenant. I am following the Microsoft tutorial on how to upload the keys, but when I call: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/$appObjId for the customer tenants, I get an error saying that the resource is missing. The only place where I can set the keys is in the BaseTenant under “App registration.”

Can you paste the screenshot of the Enterprise application in customer tenant?

What do you want to clarify?

Any update on the issue?


Note that: To provide custom claims in an Azure Identity token in a multi-tenant scenario set acceptMappedClaims as True and requestedAccessTokenVersion as 2 in the base tenant application.

Created a Microsoft Entra ID application, and in the manifest, I updated the values:
"acceptMappedClaims": true,
"requestedAccessTokenVersion": 2


In the Customer tenant the application will be created as an Enterprise application/Service principal:

The application in the customer tenant will not be visible in App registration blade.
To get the Service principal in the customer tenant, make use of below query:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/ServicePrincipalObjID



As the manifest is updated in the base tenant application you can directly add custom claims in application present in Customer tenant like below:


Generate the tokens:
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id : BaseTenantClientID
grant_type : authorization_code
scope : scope
redirect_uri : RedirectURL
code : Code
client_secret : BaseTenantClientSecret


In ID token, claims are displayed (Customer Tenant):


The claims will be displayed in the access token too.

Reference:
azure active directory - Custom Claims in a Multitenant Microsoft Entra App - Stack Overflow by me
